# jQuery: Button cause validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: Button cause validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299471/jquery-button-cause-validation)

I have a form with a submit button. This submit button validate my form with jQuery.
The problem is, in my form I have some  with onclick's event which call javascript method. But when these "non-submit" button are clicked, the form is validated.

How I can use  without trigger the validation of the form?

Answer (score 0):

From what it sounds like you need something like this:

```
$('#formid').submit(function(){
    //validate here
});
```

this is assuming you  have an input of type submit

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on insufficient information. 
Do you validate form on submit event? Your problem seems like you use  without specifying type (default type is "submit"). In that case try:

```
<button type="button" id="myButton">Non validating action</button>
```

Otherwise you could use variable indicating whether validation is required. In your validating function just check state of that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work for you?

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#clickMe').click(function(e){
        alert("click me!");
    });

    $('#clickMeAgain').click(function(e){
        alert("click me again!");
    });

    $('#submitMe').click(function(e){
        alert("submit me!");

        if(formIsValidated){
            $('form').submit();
        }
    });
});

<form>
    <input type="button" id="clickMe" value="Click Me"/>
    <input type="button" id="clickMeAgain" value="Click Me Again"/>

    <input type="button" id="submitMe" value="Submit Me"/>
</form>
```