# jQuery: Button cause validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In my form I have a normal submit button which validate my form with, for example, I have

```
$("#formTest").submit(function (e) {
        alert('test');
});

<form id="formTest">
    <input type="text"/>
    <button>Test</button>
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

But when I click on the "Test" (not the "Save" button) the alert() is displayed.
Here is a simple exemple, but in my case, jQuery validate all my input in this case.

How I can have a button with no submit effect?

Than You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically **this has nothing to do with validation**. This is just pure form submission. To prevent your form brom being submitted on your *Test* button click, you should attach a click event handler to it and cancel event's propagation.

```
$("button").click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

### Why does this happen anyway?

The thing is that when you click your *Test* button, your form gets submitted because default button type (when not provided as in your case) will be **submit**. Check [W3C Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5).

This simply means that by providing a `type="button"` would change this submission behaviour as well. But this depends on the problem at hand (which is clearly not the one presented in the simplified example).

Comment: Perfect, I just add <button **type="button"**> and it's works! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you will want to make a handler for the button, and put a preventDefault() on it's event.

```
$('button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('i clicked!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change <button>Test</button>
into
<input type="button" id="test" >Test</input>